# I don't understand a "Personal Version - Not licensed" error on my Fortran FTN95

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, fortran95

So I have successfully downloaded Fortran FTN95 (Free Personal Edition) from SilverFrost and I am trying to run a program but I am always getting the following error:

"This program was built with a Personal Version of FTN95 - Not licensed for research or commercial use"

My code is not research-oriented nor is it being used for any commercial purposes and it is being run on my own personal laptop, yet this message keeps popping up and will not allow me to run the code.  I don't know if it's the wrong version of Fortran that I have downloaded? I also tried Windows 8 and 7 withe same result.

Comment: What do the support people on their forum say? [http://forums.silverfrost.com]

Comment: You have to email the support team at Fortran to register for a username and password before you can post on the forum.  I emailed them about a few hours ago and am still waiting.

Comment: What kind of code are you running? Isn't it just a nag box at the start of the program, which however continues to run?

Comment: As Vladimir says, it is just a nag box.  If you don't want to appear then you have to buy a silverfrost compiler.  This is specified in FAQ 4 of http://www.silverfrost.com/32/ftn95/ftn95_personal_edition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It says in the first paragraph at http://www.silverfrost.com/32/ftn95/personal_edition.aspx

"It is strictly for personal use or evaluation purposes. You can use it at home on your own personal projects. You can use it to evaluate FTN95 with the intention of purchasing it later. Any applications you create with it will display a banner announcing that it is the personal edition."

Showing the banner is as intended. If you use it a lot maybe think about buying it.